# Check if user is on LAN

Tags: php, drupal, lan

I'm making a drupal website that will be used in a museum. They want to send a mail with a printable page to the user. If the user is currently in the museum, they want to send the mail to the reception too, so the page can be printed in the museum.

I'm assuming the best way to check whether the person is in the museum or not is by determining if the user is on the LAN or not. Is there any way to do this in php and/or drupal?

Comment: That will depend on how you define "user is in the museum" - will they be logged in on a domain controller? What kind of architecture is the museum's network using? This will need more technical detail.

Comment: @Pekka To be honest, I don't know. We have yet to receive the technical details from the museum.

Comment: ahh, I misread: you mean if the user *visiting the web site* is currently in the museum. That is definitely easier, as their IP will be telling. KarmicDice's approach might work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar project.

What I did was checked if the user's IP address is the same to that of the LAN's external IP. If it is, it does the thing.

You fetch IP address using

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

then, put this value under if-else.

Simple?

Comment: I think you mean `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: This might do the trick :) The only problem is that I do not have access to their servers yet. We're on a test server in our office for the moment.

Comment: this would work but what if the IP address changes? then your solution will be broken. So better make sure it doesn't

Comment: @omoabobade Please read his question again. If he is on the SAME LAN, then, if server IP changes, so does the LAN IP... they will be consistent....

Comment: @SimonVerbeke If you believe this has solved your query please click on the tick, maybe? ;)

Comment: Smart @SimonVerbeke ;) :D

omoabobade he is actually yet to get all technical details...

Comment: @omoabobade The server and the computer will be in the museum on a LAN. So if the server sees that computer is used, it will send a mail to the reception too. Else only the user will receive a mail

Comment: Hmm.. It turns out it doesn't work on our test servers because we use our local IPs. It should work on the museum's servers, but we can't test it at the moment. So I'm going to go with a user-based solution instead, which shouldn't be much more code than the IP-based solution. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Ideally, a loopback check is always useful. When you will have the server in museum, (i.e. live server), you can always resolve it to your hostname without worrying about Ip address change (if at all) using `gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);` . Wish you luck! :)